# Problem on combinatorics and counting.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, combinatorial-game-theory, combinatorial-proofs

A delegation of 4 students is to be selected from 12 students; find number of ways of doing so if;
a) two students wish to be included together only in the delegation
b) if two particular students refuse to be together and two other students wish to be together in delegation only

Well first off, i thought the wording was really weird. I don't understand what 'in delegation' means. Looking at answer, i assumed it is

in case a) that either both are selected or both not selected and

in case b) two students don't want to be together and the other two want to be together irrespective of whether they are both in or out

So my first question is, Is this what the question is actually asking?

My solutions;

a) if both are selected ${10\choose2}$ and if both are not selected, then ${10\choose4}$. So total = 45 + 210 = 255.

b) Let $H_1 , H_2$ be kids who don't want to be together and $L_1 , L_2 $ be kids who want to be together. So, only one of $H_1 / H_2$ will be selected.

case 1) $L_1, L_2$ not selected => ${8\choose4} \cdot 2$

case 2) $L_1,L_2$ selected  => ${8\choose2} \cdot 2$

So total = 196.  But actual answer is 226

I don't understand where I am wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: for b, may i know why you're multiplying by 2 ?

Comment: @across one for when $h_1$ is selected and once when $h_2$ is

Comment: what about the case when both are not selected

Comment: @across both dont wanna be together

Comment: is the answer 216 or 226?

Comment: @across sorry 226

Comment: using part a, im getting $(45-1) + (210- {8\choose 2}) = 226$

Comment: i feel your mistake is you're missing the case when h1, h2 both are NOT selected

Comment: @across oh then i think the question is worded weirdly

Comment: h1, h2 not together involves 3 cases :   `only h1 alone selected, only h2 alone selected, both h1, h2 not selected`; this is same as :  `all cases - h1,h2 both selected`

Comment: Aditya definitely agree the question is phrased weirdly

Comment: @across so i think question meant $h_1 , h_2$ both not selected. But then in part a) and part b) , both would have different meaing

Comment: Aditya I did not say that. I think your version of the question is correct and more clear `case b) two students don't want to be together and the other two want to be together irrespective of whether they are both in or out`

Comment: @across i am sorry for my above comment. i dont know what i was thinking. all i mean is if they both arent selected, they are both still together

Comment: Ah ok I get you now. It doesn't matter because they are both together OUTSIDE the delegation.

Comment: @across oh ok thanks ! this question was definitely very weird, they should have specified this. It wasn't even tough which makes it all the more annyoing. I wasted so much time on this lol. Thanks1

Comment: Happens haha and agree question is very poorly worded. More clear:  `case b) two students don't want to be together IN THE DELEGATION and the other two want to be together IN THE DELEGATION `